# retrieve data using INNER JOIN not expecting result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking for someeklse to cast an eye on my query, basically I am wanting to get a  list of users whentheir user_id is apart of a group table. I have three tables:

```
users
  user_id

groups
  group_id

user_group_join
  user_id
  group_id
```

So, I am wanting to get out the users names from the rows from the `user_group_join` table.

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT users.OrderID, user_group_join.user_id, users.first_name
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_group_join
ON users.user_id=user_group_join.user_id";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo'<p>' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>';
};

?>
```

I have tried to execute the above and getting no results I am expecting, mainly errors like:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\admin\new_doc.php on line 16
```

Comment: What does mysql_error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out so for anyone else having some issues with JOIN tables I simply maaged to keep trialing the query and here is my end resuklts:

```
$q = "SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name, users.user_id, user_group_join.user_id
FROM users, user_group_join
WHERE users.user_id = user_group_join.user_id";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    echo'<p>' . $row['first_name'] . ' '. $row['last_name'] . '</p>';
```